# JAVA CSVファイルを NIOでどうやって読みますか。

Tags: java

私はDesktopの中であるCSVファイルをJAVAにNIOを使って利用したいです。
でもファイルを読んだらすぐエラーが発生します。
現在CSVファイルの内容は

```
id,date,contents
1,2017-06-12,テストデータ
2,2017-06-12,テストデータ1
3,2017-06-13,残り分
4,2017-06-13,会社
5,2017-06-13,kaisixaya
```

これです。

欲しいoutputは System.out.println(currentLine); すれば上と同じに出力したいです。
半分はNIO使って半分はただIO使って解決はしましたが、全部NIO使って出力したいです。

```java
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\yahoo\\Desktop\\ScheduleManagement\\ScheduleData.csv");

try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))){

 String currentLine = null;

  while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){

    System.out.println(currentLine); 

  }

}catch(IOException ex){

  ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: 正常に動作しそうに見えますが、どのようなエラーが発生するんですか？

Comment: #エラーの内容はjava.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
 at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
 at com.google.javacodetest.NioTest.main(NioTest.java:19)　　　　　これですネットで探して解決したいですがなかなかできないですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントの

> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
>   at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java‌​:281)
>   ...

から判断すると、文字コードの問題だと思います。Charset.forName("UTF-8")の"UTF-8"を変更するか、CSVファイルを保存する際の文字コードをUTF-8に変更すれば、解決するのではないかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました韓国人の中で同じ悩みを拝見させていただきました。この結果ExcelファイルはUTF-8に貯蔵ができませんなのでメモ帳でUTF-8に貯蔵したらできました。